# Dynamic block with optional data

Tags: dynamic, terraform

let say we have this locals:

```
locals = {
  schemas = [
    {
      name                = "is_cool"
      attribute_data_type = "Boolean"
      mutable             = true
      required            = false
    },
    {
      name                = "firstname"
      attribute_data_type = "String"
      mutable             = true
      required            = false
      min_length          = 1
      max_length          = 256
    }
  ]
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to use `dynamic` to build schemas and when the schema is a string I would like to add the `string_attribute_constraints` block.

This is what I did so far but it adds an empty `string_attribute_constraints` block when the schema is Boolean

```
dynamic "schema" {
  for_each = var.schemas
  content {
    name                = schema.value.name
    attribute_data_type = schema.value.attribute_data_type
    mutable             = schema.value.mutable
    required            = schema.value.required

    string_attribute_constraints {
      min_length = lookup(schema.value, "min_length", null)
      max_length = lookup(schema.value, "max_length", null)
    }
  }
}
```

**terraform plan:**

```
      + schema {
          + attribute_data_type = "Boolean"
          + mutable             = true
          + name                = "is_cool"
          + required            = false

          + string_attribute_constraints {}
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a second nested `dynamic` block to tell Terraform how many `string_attribute_constraints` blocks to generate based on your rule:

```
dynamic "schema" {
  for_each = var.schemas
  content {
    name                = schema.value.name
    attribute_data_type = schema.value.attribute_data_type
    mutable             = schema.value.mutable
    required            = schema.value.required

    dynamic "string_attribute_constraints" {
      for_each = schema.attribute_data_type == "String" ? [1] : []
      content {
        min_length = lookup(schema.value, "min_length", null)
        max_length = lookup(schema.value, "max_length", null)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works by making the `for_each` for the nested `dynamic` be an empty list in the case where we don't want to generate any blocks, and making it a single-element list in the case where we do. Since we need no references to `string_attribute_constraints.key` or `string_attribute_constraints.value` inside the block, we can set the value of the single element to anything, and so I just set it to `1` as an arbitrary placeholder.

Comment: cool cool that works. just edit the code to:
```for_each = schema.value.attribute_data_type```

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic "schema" {
    for_each = local.my_schema
    content {
      name                = schema.value.name
      attribute_data_type = schema.value.attribute_data_type
      mutable             = schema.value.mutable
      required            = schema.value.required

      dynamic "string_attribute_constraints" {
        for_each = schema.value.attribute_data_type == "String" ? [1] : []
        content {
          min_length = lookup(schema.value, "min_length", 0)
          max_length = lookup(schema.value, "max_length", 2048)
        }
      }

      dynamic "number_attribute_constraints" {
        for_each = schema.value.attribute_data_type == "Number" ? [1] : []
        content {
          min_value = lookup(schema.value, "min_value", 0)
          max_value = lookup(schema.value, "max_value", 2048)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```